# Drop down menu in Bootstrap Business (drupal 7) theme is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, drupal-7

I have installed Bootstrap Business theme in Drupal 7. The 'Show as expanded' option has enabled in menu list. But drop down  menu is not working.
There are no any javascript errors while loading the page. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop down menu is depend on some jquery libraries. You have to install [jquery update module](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) and [superfish module](https://drupal.org/project/superfish).

After enabled both modules, download the [superfish library from github](https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal/archive/1.x.zip) and extract it's content to `/sites/all/libraries/superfish` in the durpal installation.

Add following code in `path to superfish library` area in superfish module configuration.

```
sites/all/libraries/superfish/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/jquery.bgiframe.min.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/superfish.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/supersubs.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/supposition.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/sftouchscreen.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
```

Then change jquery version to 1.7 in jquery update module configuration.

Finally go to the `structure/blocks` and place a superfish item in navigation region.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your Drupal configuration is

- a) not using @import to get it's directives in
- b) not using    respond.js to provide media query support to legacy browsers such as    IE8

There are known problems when using certain configurations with the latest builds of bootstrap , and this information is clearley communicated in the BS3 docs as the following snippet shows:

> Respond.js and @import
>
> Respond.js doesn't work with CSS that's referenced via @import. In particular, some Drupal configurations are known to use @import. See the Respond.js docs for details.

Failing that, then in order to get any more in depth help, you'll need to start providing code examples of what you've tried to do, and more in depth explanations of what you've tried, not tried and what you expected to happen vs what did happen.